# Finding and deleting files with a specific date

Tags: linux, find, rm

how to delete the files that created on `Aug 7` with the name `DBG_A_sql*` 
 under `/tmp`

as the following example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root   51091 Aug  7 11:22 DBG_A_sql.2135
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root   15283 Aug  7 11:22 DBG_A_sql.2373
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root   51091 Aug  7 11:22 DBG_A_sql.2278
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    9103 Aug  7 11:22 DBG_A_sql.2485
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    9116 Aug  7 11:22 DBG_A_sql.2573
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    9140 Aug  7 11:22 DBG_A_sql.2679
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root   15695 Aug  7 11:22 DBG_A_sql.2897
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `find`. Calculate date according to your requirement and use,

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f -name "DBG_A_sql*" -print
```

After confirming it delete them,

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f -name "DBG_A_sql*" -delete
```

Comment: `-newerct "08-07" -not -newerct "08-08"` if you'd like because **ctime** is a difference between file date and now.

Comment: `find / -newerct 'Aug 7' -print | grep filename` or `find / -newerct "08-07" -print | grep filename` I think he meant this.

Comment: Note that `-newrct` and `-ctime` have nothing to do with _creation time_. They're for change time.

Comment: You can't pass the output of `ls -l` to `xargs` like that, that doesn't make any sense. (note that `ls -l` doesn't output the creation time either, your `find` approach was a lot better than that, only you'd probably want `-mtime`/`-newermt`)

Comment: `-mtime -8` is for files last modified within the last 8 days.

Answer (score 10):

For a start, finding files *created* on a certain time is a bit hard, since the creation time isn't usually saved anywhere or is hard to get at. What you have is `mtime`, or the last modification time, and `ctime` which is the "change" time, updated on any changes to the inode. I'll assume you want the modification time.

---

Finding files modified on a given date turned out to be mildly interesting, since `find` appears to make it a bit hard to get it right with files created on exactly midnight.

If we know the relative time (i.e. it was yesterday), we could use 
`find -daystart -mtime 1`, but it finds the file modified on the wrong midnight, `Aug 8 00:00`. However, this seems to work:

```
find dir/ -daystart -mtime +0 \! -mtime +1 -ls
```

If don't want to calculate the relative time, and your `find` has `-newerXY`:

```
find dir/ -newermt 'Aug 7 00:00' \! -newermt 'Aug 8 00:00' -ls
```

Again, this gets the files created exactly on midnight wrong, because the comparison is "newer", not "newer or as old as". Though if your system has subsecond precision for timestamps, it might be hard to hit that, but happens if you test with files created by `touch`...

A hairy workaround to that would be something like this:

```
find dir/ -newermt 'Aug 6 23:59:59.999999999' \! -newermt 'Aug 7 23:59:59.999999999' -ls
```

In any case, add the necessary `-name "DBG_A_sql*"` to only take the files with the correct name. You can replace the `-ls` at the end with `-delete` to delete the files instead of listing. (`-ls`, `-delete` and `-newerXY` exist at least in GNU find and the BSD find on OS X.)

---

Of course you could actually parse the text representation of the date, but `ls` makes it hard to get right if some joker creates files with unprintable characters in them. Sure, the example files don't have any such, but in general, anyone could create them, especially in `/tmp`.

(Though with `| xargs rm` you'd just miss those files, and since file names can't contain slashes, it would be hard for anyone to point your `rm` to another directory.)

Comment: _creation time_ or _birth time_ is often stored nowadays, but on some systems like Linux-based ones, hard to retrieve.

Answer (score 5):

Just bash loop

```
for file in /tmp/DBG_A_sql* ; do
    [ "$(date -I -r "$file")" == "2016-08-07" ] && rm "$file"
done
```

Comment: How is that _pure bash_? `bash` has no `date` or `rm` builtin as far as I know. Note that it implies the GNU implementation of `date`. See `zsh` or `ksh93` for shells that can do it with only builtins (though I wouldn't see the point here).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. Agree. Have edited.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by *created*, you mean *last modified* (which is the time reported by `ls -l`), with `zsh`:

```
autoload age # best in ~/.zshrc
rm /tmp/DBG_A_sql*(e:age 2016-08-07:)
```